# C++ 11 random number generation not working

Tags: c++, random, numbers, mt19937

```
//My trial program
#include<iostream>
#include<random>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //USed to initialize (seed) the random number generator
    random_device sd{};

    // The random number generator
    mt19937 engine {sd()};

    //Uniformly distribute random numbers in [1...10]
    uniform_int_distribution <> dis{1, 50};

    //Generate a random integer
    int x {dis(engine)};

    //Print it 

    cout<<x<<"\n";

    return 0;

}
```

I have used the code above to a generate random number between 1 to 50. But whenever I run the program, the random number generated is the same. An online course that I am taking has this code and it works perfectly fine on the instructor's clang compiler. I am using gcc compiler. Can anyone tell me what needs to be done please? thank you!!

Comment: keep changing the seed

Comment: mt19937 engine {sd()};   any rand value here

Comment: Are you by any chance using MinGW? That has or used to have some trouble with `std::random_device`.

Comment: *"//Uniformly distribute random numbers in [1...10]
    uniform_int_distribution <> dis{1, 50};"*: Why commenting code is wrong.

Comment: @HariomSingh The code that I was referring to did not have any rand value at mt19937 engine {sd()}; and it was still working.

Comment: @BaummitAugen yes, I am using MinGW

Comment: [o_O](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a3da2eb625d4693)

Comment: @BaummitAugen TY

Comment: @HariomSingh TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) does not have to really be a random device.  It can be a wrapper around an unseeded `rand` which would give you the same value every time you use it.  This means your seed for `engine` would be the same which means the pseudo-random sequence it generates would be the same as well.

One way you could get around this is to use the current as a seed like

```
auto seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
mt19937 engine {seed};
```

But this can be manipulated via external processes and isn't very fined grained so multiple instances seeded at the same time could all make the same sequence.

Comment: How to work around this limitation so that it generates a pseudo random code?

Comment: @AbhiJoe seed it with a timestamp.

Comment: @AbhiJoe Just updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

From [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) :

> std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. **In this case each std::random_device object may generate the same number sequence.**

Although it's not ideal for it's users, an implementation is allowed to have the behavior you described.